# Recall sub-function and continue main program execution in Python

Tags: python, function

Consider the following structure

```
    main_func()
{
        sub_func1()
        sub_func2()
        sub_func3()
        .
        .
        .
        sub_funcN()
        exit()
}
```

I wish to implement a 'go-back to previous function' functionality while keeping the sequence of execution intact.

For example:
During execution of main function, the user selected 'go-back to previous function' in sub_func3() to go to sub_func2() and then continue the same sequence of the main program i.e sub_func2() -> sub_func3 () -> .... -> sub_funcN() -> exit()
How can this be achieved?

Looking forwards to your response

Comment: With generator functions acting as continuations maybe, but it sounds pretty hairy. Can you explain your actual use case?

Comment: Use case is to collect information from the user using CLI menus
User is to be provided with an option to go back to the previous menu and continue execution

Comment: Well, in that case just use the call stack?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to handle this depending on the actual use case, but one idea is to have each `sub_func` return a flag indicating whether to advance to the next function or rewind to the previous one, and then use that to move an index through a list:

```
def sub_func1() -> int:
    if input("Go back? ") == "y":
        return -1
    # do other stuff
    return 1

sub_funcs = [
    sub_func0,
    sub_func1,
    sub_func2,
    sub_func3,
    # ...
    sub_funcN
]


i = 0
while i < len(sub_funcs):
    i += sub_funcs[i]()
```

A variation on this might be to have the sub_funcs raise a `GoBack` exception that is caught by a `try/except` in the caller to decrement the index, with the default being to increment it (that way each function doesn't need to explicitly `return 1` in order to advance the state machine).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Class (let's call it OperationClass).
main() function creates an instance of OperationClass.

On OperationClass you also define the operation flow, back() and next() methods().

So you can make your main() function call OperatorClass.next() or OperatorClass.back(), and this methods knows the flow and what function (methods) is supposed to be executed

Comment: When answering to coding questions it's usually better a snipped of code :)